# I cannot figure out how to fix this error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java

Below is the page of code that I have written for my program that I am completing for my Internal Assessment. In other classes, I have declared all the objects and arrays that are used within this method, incase you were wondering. The issue I am having is not that I am unable to run this, but that when I run file in order to check that the code functions correctly, I receive this error code:

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at iaversion1.MainMethod.main(MainMethod.java:57)
/Users/dylan.ramirez/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

The line to which the exception is referring to is:

```
ArrayToB[arrayCount] = ToBTemp;
```

What I am trying to do is to store a variable from the already imported database, which is divided by column and can be seen doing this in this code below just after the while loop, in the temporary variable so that it can then be used in array ToB which is declared outside of the main method. The problem that I have, is that when I run the file, even though I am asking for it to do this:

```
System.out.println(ArrayToB[3].getTypeOfBody());
```

it instead outputs nothing and provides me with the exception that I posted above.

Can anybody help me with the issue that I am having. If for any reason you don't understand anything in the code, please do not hesitate to message me. REALLY NEED HELP!

Also, just for some extra information, the .csv file which is being imported is split into 18 columns and 6 rows, this is the .csv:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainMethod {

 static ToB ArrayToB[] = new ToB [4];   
 static Diet ArrayDiet [] = new Diet [4];
 static DietAttributes ArrayDietAtributes [] = new DietAttributes [4];
 static Activities ArrayActivities [] = new Activities [6];

 static int arrayCount = 0;


   public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String csvFile = "/Users/dylan.ramirez/Documents/COMPUTER 
SCIENCE/IA/IAVersion1/IAVersion1/src/iaversion1/DATABASE - Sheet1.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            //this line separates each column of the csv file
            String[] databaseColumn = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            //this variables store each individual column
            String sTypeOfBody = databaseColumn[0];
            String sAppearance = databaseColumn[1];
            String sDietDescription = databaseColumn[2];
            String sFoodExample = databaseColumn [3];
            String sBicepsExercise = databaseColumn [4];
            String sGluteusExercise = databaseColumn [5];
            String sAbdominalsExercise = databaseColumn [6];
            String sQuadricepsExercise = databaseColumn [7];
            String sPectoralsExercise = databaseColumn [8];
            String sDietName = databaseColumn [9];
            String sBodyNutrientsPercent = databaseColumn [10];          
            String sMuscularEnduranceActivity = databaseColumn [11];
            String sAgilityActivity = databaseColumn [12];
            String sPowerActivity = databaseColumn [13];
            String sBalanceActivity = databaseColumn [14];
            String sCoordinationActivity = databaseColumn [15];
            String sSpeedActivity = databaseColumn [16];
            String sNutrients = databaseColumn [17];


            ToB ToBTemp = new ToB(sTypeOfBody, sAppearance);
            ArrayToB[arrayCount] = ToBTemp;

            Diet DietTemp = new Diet(sDietName, sDietDescription);
            ArrayDiet[arrayCount] = DietTemp;

            DietAttributes DietAttributesTemp = new DietAttributes(sDietName, sDietDescription, sNutrients, sBodyNutrientsPercent, sFoodExample);

            Activities ActivitiesTemp = new Activities (sMuscularEnduranceActivity, sAgilityActivity, sPowerActivity, sBalanceActivity, sCoordinationActivity, sSpeedActivity, sBicepsExercise, sGluteusExercise, sAbdominalsExercise, sQuadricepsExercise, sPectoralsExercise);
            ArrayActivities [arrayCount] = ActivitiesTemp;

            arrayCount = arrayCount + 1;


        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } 
    System.out.println(ArrayToB[3].getTypeOfBody());

}

}
```

Comment: "Also, just for some extra information, the .csv file which is being imported is split into 18 columns and 6 rows, this is the .csv:" but your `ArrayToB` size is only 4.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: I tried debugging it but I didn't really help me much to figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like ArrayToB has 4 objects, but your CSV file has 6 rows. Once the loop passes the first four rows, you are out of the array's bounds.

Comment: Thank you! I have deleted 2 rows of the database just to check if it would work, and yes it does.